# Apply javascript definitions to appended string with Ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to append some HTML strings to the page. But I have a confusing problem. I have many HTML elements which must be interpreted by Javascript. For example just see the simple bootstrap tooltip:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<span title="Its the tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" >test</span>');
```

How can I apply javascript functions and definitions to my HTML string? 
I notice that I can't append them one by one by for example by .tooltip() function.

The complete code is here :

HTML

```
<div class="users-page">
    <div id="myDiv" ></div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="URL/page/20"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click','.users-page .pagination a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: targetUrl,
        success: function(data){
                var html = '<span title="Its the tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" >test</span>';
                var $html = $(html);
                $('#myDiv').append($html);
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain again what you are trying to do? Bind click events to DOM elements? or append a script element along with your span element? please clarify

Comment: Yes, I edited the post and clarify it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
var html = "<span title='Its the tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' >test</span>";
var $html = $(html);
//do what you want with $html
$("#myDiv").append($html);
```

Comment: It's indipendent from AJAX, you are executing the code in a function. If your problem is that the tooltip does not work that's because you are not running the `.tooltip()` method.